# can you recall a method in a case statement ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to know if this is a okay way to do a loop in the case statement. Is it okay to recall the method if the response (user input) is bad input? Is there a better way?

```
def game_type # Selecting humans or computers as players
    puts "Please select game type by number:"
    puts "1 - human vs human"
    puts "2 - computer vs computer"
    puts "3 - human vs computer"
    response = gets.chomp.to_i

    case response
    when 1
      puts "human vs human"
    when 2
      puts "computer vs computer"
    when 3
      puts "human vs computer"
    else
      game_type
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling method recursively like that is a very bad thing because for each recursive call, an additional depth is added to the call stack, and you cannot predict how deep it is going to be, making it bad for performance. In general, recursion should be avoided if possible. In this case, use a loop, which does not require recursive call.

```
def game_type
  loop do
    puts <<~_
      Please select game type by number:
      1 - human vs human
      2 - computer vs computer
      3 - human vs computer
    _
    response = gets.to_i
    case response
    when 1
      puts "human vs human"
      break
    when 2
      puts "computer vs computer"
      break
    when 3
      puts "human vs computer"
      break
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard pattern for this type of interaction is to have an `else` branch that complains and sends you back for another loop.

One thing to keep in mind when doing Ruby is you should try and define things like this in a regular structure to avoid a lot of repetition. The "Don't Repeat Yourself" (DRY) principle is very important. Keep it dry!

So in this case:

```
GAME_TYPE_LIST = [
  "Human vs. Human",
  "Computer vs. Computer",
  "Human vs. Computer"
]

# Convert this list to a hash indexed by 1, 2, 3, etc.
GAME_TYPES = Hash[GAME_TYPE_LIST.each_with_index.map { |type, i| [ i + 1, type ] }]
```

That makes it pretty easy to add more types in the future, plus also super easy to present your menu:

```
GAME_TYPES.each do |i, type|
  puts '%d - %s' % [ i, type ]
end
```

Likewise, when it comes time to pick:

```
game_type = nil

begin
  puts "Enter type:"

  game_type = gets.chomp.to_i
end while (!GAME_TYPES[game_type])
```

That will keep looping util you get it right.

Comment: Come on, you know better than using `chomp` like that.

Comment: @sawa What's so awful about stripping off the newline? `to_i` might not care, but I like to feed it clean data.

Answer (score -1):

> I want to know if this is a okay way to do a loop in the case statement. Is it okay to recall the method if the response (user input) is bad input?

While you *can* do that, as sawa said, that's not good practice in Ruby, for performance related reasons.

> Is there a better way?

Rather than use recursion, use `loop`:

```
GAME_TYPES = {
  1 => "human vs computer",
  2 => "computer vs computer",
  3 => "human vs human"
}

def game_type
  loop do      
    puts <<~___
      Please select game type by number:
      1 - human vs human
      2 - computer vs computer
      3 - human vs computer
    ___
    selection = gets.to_i  
    if game_type_str = GAME_TYPES[selection]
      puts game_type_str
      break
    end
  end
end
```

(I also changed your code to use a dictionary rather than a `case` statement, which makes the code much more succinct than having a bunch of `break` statements).

Comment: "I **also** changed **your** code to use a dictionary"---Isn't that the **only** thing you changed from **my** answer? Please do not parasite on other answers. If you have anything to say, write it in your own words, using your own code, not pretending as if you wrote it.

Comment: Sorry you think I copied it, but really there's not a hundred ways to change a `while` block into a `loop` one... I wrote the code in sublime before posting and saw your answer only after that (after which I edited to mention your answer, which I also upvoted).

Comment: It is hard to believe that using a single `puts` method with a heredoc with the same mode `~`, with the same identifier `_`, and precisely removing the redundant `chomp` was all coincidence.

Comment: Really now? You think you're the only one in the world who uses `HEREDOC`s or removes pointless `chomp`s on `gets`? edit: there, I changed the `HEREDOC` name, おめでとう！